# Access controls located on the main form when the child form closes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have created a main form which is always visible to users... its got some menu options. This form (Main) has got a number of hidden buttons which I am trying to unhide from another child form once the child form closes. My question is..."how do you transfer control from child to Main or reference the buttons on the Main form once the child have close. Thanks in advance for all help and suggestions. Here is what I have got so far:-

```
 //This event is in the child's form..

 private void Registerbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   .
   .  // carry out some work and close
   .


 }

 this.Close();
 Showbuttons();//custom procedure


 //custom procedure use to display all the hidden buttons on Main form
 public void Showbutton(){
      foreach (Control c in ((Main)MdiParent).Controls){
          if (c is Button){
               ((Button)c).Show();
          }
      }

 }
```

Comment: You should try registering the childs closing events in the main form and then have the Main do whatever is needed to its buttons. Actively changing the parent form from a child is bad practice.

Answer (score 3):

Subscribe to the child form's `FormClosed` event:

```
var childForm = new ChildForm();
childForm.FormClosed += ChildFormClosedHandler;
childForm.Show();
```

Then once the child form closes it will show all the buttons that are direct descendants of the form.

```
private void ChildFormClosedHandler(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Button button in this.Controls.OfType<Button>()){
        button.Visible = true;
    } 
}
```

If you only want the buttons to be shown after some specific function then you may need to set some property on the child and do a check through the `sender` argument.